# React Apollo Testing is not working. Query data is always coming undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, react-testing-library

I am getting loading state only and data as undefined in testing. I don't know why I am following everything in the given example. Please help.

Testing file. When i am waiting thsi line toexecute `await wait(() => getByTestId('edit-category'));`. It is giving response data of query as undefined. 
Error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCategory' of undefined` 
Line 34 on `editConatinerCategory.tsx` => `category={data!.getCategory!}`

```
import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { cleanup, wait } from 'react-testing-library';
import { customRender } from '../../../test-utils/customRender';
import { EditCategoryContainer } from './Container';

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
  console.error;
});
console.error = jest.fn();

const getCategoryMock = {
  request: {
    query: gql`
      query getCategory($id: Int!) {
        getCategory(id: $id) {
          id
          name
          active
          position
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: 1
    }
  },
  result: {
    data: {
      getCategory: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'category',
        active: true,
        position: 1
      }
    }
  }
};

describe('create edit category module', () => {
  test('Rendering correct', async () => {
    const { container, debug, getByTestId } = customRender(<EditCategoryContainer />, [
      getCategoryMock
    ]);
    await wait(() => getByTestId('edit-category'));
    await wait(() => expect(container).toMatchSnapshot());
//Getting this TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCategory' of undefined. Because i am data as undefined from my query response

  });
});
```

CustomRender.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-testing-library';
import { MockedProvider, MockedResponse } from 'react-apollo/test-utils';
import { Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

export const customRender = (
  node: JSX.Element | null,
  mocks?: MockedResponse[],
  {
    route = '/',
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] })
  } = {}
) => {
  return {
    history,
    ...render(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>{node}</Switch>
        </Router>
      </MockedProvider>
    )
  };
};
```

EditCategoryContainer.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { Spin } from 'antd';
import {
  AddCategoryComponent,
  GetCategoryComponent
} from '../../../generated/graphql';
import { EditCategory } from './Edit';
import { LoadingComponent } from '../../../components/LoadingComponent';

export const EditCategoryContainer = withRouter(({ history, match }) => {
  const id: number = parseInt(match.params.id, 10);
  return (
    <GetCategoryComponent
      variables={{
        id
      }}
    >
      {({ data, loading: getCategoryLoading }) => {
        console.log(getCategoryLoading, 'getCategoryLoading');
        if (getCategoryLoading) {
          return <LoadingComponent />;
        }
        if (data && !data.getCategory) {
          return <div>Category not found!</div>;
        }
        console.log(data);
        return (
          <AddCategoryComponent>
            {(addCategory, { loading, error }) => {
              return (
                <EditCategory
                  data-testid="edit-category"
                  category={data!.getCategory!}
                  loading={loading || getCategoryLoading}
                  onSubmit={values => {
                    addCategory({ variables: values }).then(() => {
                      history.push('/dashboard/categories');
                    });
                  }}
                />
              );
            }}
          </AddCategoryComponent>
        );
      }}
    </GetCategoryComponent>
  );
});
```

Edit: 
I tried @mikaelrs solution which is passed match. But it is not working. I also tried to pass id:1 as fixed. But it is still giving error.

```
 <GetCategoryComponent
      variables={{
        id:1
      }}
    >
...rest of code.
</GetCategoryComponent>
```

This is not working. My query without veriable is working fine. Mutation is also working fine. I am having only problem with this. When i have to pass like varible like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I do to wait for the loading state of the `MockedProvider` to pass is to use the `wait` function from `waait`. This is actually what `Apollo` recommends as well.

So in your test you would do:

```
import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { cleanup } from 'react-testing-library';
import wait from 'waait'

import { customRender } from '../../../test-utils/customRender';
import { EditCategoryContainer } from './Container';

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
});

const getCategoryMock = {
  request: {
    query: gql`
      query getCategory($id: Int!) {
        getCategory(id: $id) {
          id
          name
          active
          position
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: 1
    }
  },
  result: {
    data: {
      getCategory: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'category',
        active: true,
        position: 1
      }
    }
  }
};

describe('create edit category module', () => {
  test('Rendering correct', async () => {
    const { container, debug } = customRender(<EditCategoryContainer />, [
      getCategoryMock
    ]);

    await wait(0);

    // Your loading state should be false after this, and your component should
    // get it's data from apollo for you to do any assertion you would like to 
    // after this point. To see that the component is rendered with data invoke 
    // the debug function from react-testing-library after this point


    debug();


    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot()
  });
});
```

Another solution is to use `react-testing-library`s `wait` function to wait for an element that would be present after the loading state switches to true.

For instance

```
describe('create edit category module', () => {
  test('Rendering correct', async () => {
    const { container, debug, queryByText } = customRender(<EditCategoryContainer />, [
      getCategoryMock
    ]);

    await wait(()=> queryByText("Some Data"));

    // Your loading state should be false after this, and your component should
    // get it's data from apollo for you to do any assertion you would like to 
    // after this point

    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot()
  });
});
```

Comment: I am using react-testing-library wait function. But it is still giving me undefined,

Comment: But you are doing an expect inside of that await function. Can you try to await the wait from 'waait', which is the recommended way of testing final state from Apollo. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/testing#testing-final-state

Comment: Tried wait also from waait library. I am still  getting same errror.

Comment: Can you show me the graphql query you are running in the component? And are you getting loading false at any point? If not, that suggests that the query you are mocking isn't matching the query you are running in your component exactly

Comment: I am creating graphqlmock like this: 
```const getCategoryMock = {
  request: {
    query: gql`
      query getCategory($id: Int!) {
        getCategory(id: $id) {
          id
          name
          active
          position
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: 1
    }
  },
  result: {
    data: {
      getCategory: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'category',
        active: true,
        position: 1
      }
    }
  }
};
```

and passing ```const mocks = [ getCategoryMock]```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to see the query you are running inside `GetCategoryComponent`

Comment: Yes, That's Hoc component which is being generated by through `graphql-code-generator` to ease the pain of writing type. 
My mutations is working fine.

Comment: I am guessing that your mock request is not matching your query. Can you post the query from the `.graphql` file you've generated the code from?

Comment: ```
query getCategory($id: Int!) {
  getCategory(id: $id) {
 id
  name
  active
  position

  }
}

```

Comment: Is this line returning the number 1? `const id: number = parseInt(match.params.id, 10);` You've mocked the query for `variables: {id: 1}` so if that does not match, it will never return

Comment: ohh okay so i have to pass match also ?

Comment: Well if you want to get id from match you would have to do that. To verify that that's the problem, you could hard-code the id to be 1 in your component and test if the MockedProvider reponds with your mocked result

Comment: I fixed Id: `1`. But it is still giving error and variables also get override if you are passing them in the request.

Comment: What are they getting overriden by? Can you create a repro, so I can take a proper look at it?

Comment: Okay I will  try that and I will let know you.

Comment: Hi, Mikelrs can you show me your solution ? Because i am confused right now. Don't know what to do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191204/discussion-between-mikaelrs-and-vikash-saini).

Comment: Tried everything. At last, adding wait from waait package did the magic. all I had to do is include await wait(0). Thanks a lot @mikaelrs

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue. Here is how I resolved my issue.

First, wait for the query to resolve, as recommended by @mikaelrs and [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/):

```js
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
```

After doing that, the `loading` property was `false`, but `data` was still `undefined`. I discovered that my **mock result object was missing a property**. Once I added that missing property to the mock result, the `data` was populated as expected.